# Javascript - Jumping between browser Tabs

Tags: javascript, browser

My program consists of two browser tabs. I open the second tab from the first tab via `window.open(..)`. Can I induce changes in the first tab from the second tab? Like sending new Ajax requests etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, since `window.open()` returns a reference to the new window, and from the new window, you can access the parent window through its `opener` property.

You should see : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp

So you could invoke functions that are in the parent from the new window (`opener.functionName()`) and invoke functions of the new window from the parent (`var newWindow : window.open(...); newWindow.functionName2()`);